# Add custom JS files from local system in JHipster Angular 2 Application

Tags: jhipster, angular2-directives

Can you guys suggest me how to add local js files in application

I have tried by adding the local JS file path in `index.html` like below

```
<script src="thirdpartyscripts/amcharts.js"></script>
```

Here `**thirdpartyscripts**` is my directory.
but getting the error like below.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdBxB.jpg)

Comment: import that file in component file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy this folder and file in your target/www folder. Or alternatively use webpack to do this for you in webpack.commons.js. Look at the last line I have added

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: './node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js', to: 'core-js-shim.min.js' },
            { from: './node_modules/swagger-ui/dist', to: 'swagger-ui/dist' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/swagger-ui/', to: 'swagger-ui' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/favicon.ico', to: 'favicon.ico' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/manifest.webapp', to: 'manifest.webapp' },
            // { from: './src/main/webapp/sw.js', to: 'sw.js' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/robots.txt', to: 'robots.txt' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/thirdparty/sth.js', to: 'thirdparty/sth.js' }
        ]),
```